# How to append to Android MediaRecorder output file

Tags: android, append, mediarecorder

I am wondering if there is a way to tell the MediaRecorder to append to an existing audio file instead of starting it over from the beginning.  In other words, I would like to call setOutputFile() with an existing file and have the new audio appended to that file instead of erasing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android MediaRecorder does not support appending.

Once you are recording the only possible actions are stop and reset.

So one option is saving as a WAV file, and then append to an existing WAV file saved on the SD card using AudioRecord instead.  AudioRecord.read() allows one to save the raw audiodata to a buffer, which you could easily append to an existing recording.