# How to add Pause and Resume functionality with MediaRecorder in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mediarecorder, pause

I am using MediaRecorder to record audio in Xamarin Android. I want to add Pause and Resume functionality to this. MediaRecorder does not have built in methods to Pause and Resume the recording. How can I accomplish this? Do I need to store separate audio files when Paused and merge them in a single audio file? If yes, then how can I implement that in Xamarin Android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pause` and `Resume` was added to `MediaRecorder` in **API 24**

> Pauses recording. Call this after start(). You may resume recording with resume() without reconfiguration, as opposed to stop().
>
> Pauses recording. Call this after start(). You may resume recording with resume() without reconfiguration, as opposed to stop()

Device running `API 23` and below, the developer would be responsible for "appending" files together if that is your app requirement.

See this SO as an example: [How to append to Android MediaRecorder output file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247402/how-to-append-to-android-mediarecorder-output-file)

Ref: [MediaRecorder Pause](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#pause())

Comment: same thing i need in android but audio is not recording just video record .I do not need to use muxer for join audio file.